# How to type cast an Array as empty String array

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I can type cast NULL as a string.
How can I type cast an empty array as an empty array of strings?
I need to solve it inside the SQL query.
The following snippet throws a ValueError: *Some of types cannot be determined after inferring*

```
df = spark.sql("select Array()").collect()

display(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found a somewhat roundabout way of doing this only with SQL:

```
select from_json("[]", "array<string>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just keeping quotes should have empty string array

```
df = spark.sql("select array('')").collect()

display(df)
```

Comment: This gives an array with one element (an empty string). I want an empty array that is typed as an array of strings